# Count If VB Function doesn't handle all kinds of Data

Tags: vba, excel

Below Excel VB code checks, similar subject lines and creates empty ranges in First Column. Once Macro triggered, input box asks me to select range where it has similar subject lines, then input box ask me to give minimum number of range to be created, then it names ranges in first column as Empty Range 1, 2 and so on. Basically to work this function efficiently Count If function in VB code should handle all type of data e.g. numbers or text. i observed that if count if function gives error value such as `#Value, #N/a or "0"` then ranges are not getting created properly. Please if you can suggest improvement then it would be really nice. I have two sheets "Raw_Data" and "Ghost", later i plan to use Ghost sheet in hidden mode.

```
`Sub Assignments()

    Dim Vall As String
    Dim Colns As Range
    Dim Numb As Variant
    Dim Cnt As Variant
    Sheets("Raw_Data").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Colns = Application.InputBox("Select a column which has similar subjects.", "Range Selection", Type:=8)
    If Not Colns Is Nothing Then
        Colnss = Colns.Column
    On Error Resume Next
        Numb = Application.InputBox("Enter the number of documents to be assigned.", "Range Selection", Type:=1)
        Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "Ranges"
        Colmns = Colnss + 1
    Thrd = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(2, Colmns).End(xlDown).Row
    If Numb <> False Then
        Range(Sheets("Ghost").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Ghost").Cells(Thrd, 1)).Value = _
        Range(Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(2, Colmns), Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(Thrd, Colmns)).Value
        Range(Sheets("Ghost").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Ghost").Cells(Thrd, 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Cntif = 2
    ABC = 1
    Rais = 0
    Do While Sheets("Ghost").Cells(Cntif, 1).Value <> ""
        Vall = Sheets("Ghost").Cells(Cntif, 1).Value
            'this should not return 0 or Error values 
    Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Raw_Data").Columns(Colmns), Vall)
                Rais = Rais + Cnt
                If Rais > Numb Or Rais = Numb Then
                    UsrNme = Sheets("Raw_Data").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Range(Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(UsrNme, 1), Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(UsrNme + (Rais - 1), 1)).Value = "Empty Range " & ABC
                    Rais = 0
                    ABC = ABC + 1
                End If
        Set Cnt = Nothing
        Cntif = Cntif + 1
    Loop
        Frst = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
        Range(Cells(Frst, 1), Cells(Thrd, 1)).Value = "Last Range"
        Columns(1).AutoFit
    End If
    End If
    End Sub`
```

Example of subjects which Count if doesn't consider, paste below in Cell B1, B2 and then try:

- Checked Write content for an F Y E thanks page - two instances :::::::::::: 1) When someone submits info and is placed with a school(s). 2) If someone was not placed with any schools. You can modify your search here, kind of thing. on F Y E - Improve & test EVERYTHING for new  & Projects
- Do you need help? ~ Creative Circle ~ Talent Update for Week Ending 25 Sep 2015

Comment: @YowE3k any help on this?

Comment: With the `On Error` statements there are too many possible sources of potential issues that could be causing your problem that there is no real way I could even guess what is wrong - I would need to step through your code to see what was happening, and I can't do that without your actual data.  All I can do is suggest is that you step through the code yourself, checking the variables as you assign values to them.